# QT4 gui interface

Tags: ros, gui, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi the past few days I've been trying to make a simple gui using Qt4 to send a msg when pressing a button and to receive an int value from a topic and display it on a label or something.

I have successfully built the qt gui using rosmake as a standalone program but i dont know exactly which steps to take to integrate a ros node in the gui.

I looked through all the tutorials(eros qt and wiki) you have here and most questions. The eros examples do provide an idea but no luck with making it work.

Does anyone have any ideas, sample code or steps needed to combine a qt app along with ros node.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30979/qt4-gui-interface/) by [opcode](https://answers.ros.org/users/2101/opcode/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-04-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-12-01**:
Hi

I wont to try the same. please can you tell me the steps you need to combine qt app with ros node? I could compile it with make. But I dont know how to run it? When i run it with ./qfoo it gives me bash: ./qfoo: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer my own question. I overlooked one of the tutorials.

I just typed: " rosrun qt_create roscreate-qt-pkg qfoo "

That finally gives a clean **working** node with a gui!!

---

Originally posted by [opcode](https://answers.ros.org/users/2101/opcode/) with karma: 46 on 2012-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-12-01**:
How do you run the qfoo package??